# Insufficient permissions for this file, unable to share link, 403

Tags: google-drive-api

```
// ... role=reader, type=anyone, with_link=true .... $perms
$service->permissions->insert($fileId, $perm); // see error below
HTTP Code: 403
[
   {
      "domain": "global",
      "reason": "forbidden",
      "message": "Insufficient permissions for this file",
      "locationType": "other",
      "location": "file.permissions"
   }
]
```

Users of a specific domain are unable to share links. The error above is not listed here [https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/handle-errors](http://ttps://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/handle-errors)

The admin of the domain is certain that "share with public" is allowed for all users of their domain.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to check if you set the scopes right for the users in order for them to access the file. See [Authorizing requests with OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#OAuth2Authorizing). The scopes are the one giving permissions to certain users on what they can do to a file or folder. See [What scope or scopes does my app need?](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#what_scope_or_scopes_does_my_app_need)

> As a general rule, choose the most restrictive scope possible, and avoid requesting scopes that your app does not actually need. Users more readily grant access to limited, clearly described scopes. Conversely, users may hesitate to grant broad access to their files unless they truly trust your app and understand why it needs the information.

You may also want to see [Perform Google Apps Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#perform_google_apps_domain-wide_delegation_of_authority). It is suggested here that you use a *service account* which will enable users to access your Google API through your web application.