# Google drive API adding ../auth/drive scope without authorized domain

Tags: google-drive-api

**Background**

I am new to Google Drive API and am trying to use a Google Drive recursive ownership change tool: https://github.com/davidstrauss/google-drive-recursive-ownership/

- OAuth 2 Scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` ([source](https://github.com/davidstrauss/google-drive-recursive-ownership/blob/master/transfer.py#L16))
- Drive API Version: `v2` ([source](https://github.com/davidstrauss/google-drive-recursive-ownership/blob/master/transfer.py#L26))

I followed [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/xtqpWG5KDXY) to generate my `client_secret.json` file.  Additionally, I added the scope `../auth/drive.file` to my OAuth consent screen (app is named `gdrive transfer ownership`).

As a practice run, I try to transfer ownership of a folder containing one `jpg` file (both located in my Google Drive, and I am the owner).  When I run the tool from my local laptop, the following happens:

1. I run [`transfer.py`](https://github.com/davidstrauss/google-drive-recursive-ownership/blob/master/transfer.py) like so:

```
python transfer.py "TestFolderName" "new_owner@gmail.com"
```

2. I copy the authorization link into my browser
3. I click through a few menus, granting permissions

> [image: Grant permission screenshot]

4. I copy the code from my browser into the program
5. The script fails to update the `jpg` file's ownership permissions, saying `"Insufficient permissions for this file"`:

```
An error occurred updating ownership permissions: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/some_text/permissions/some_num?transferOwnership=true&alt=json returned "Insufficient permissions for this file">
```

6. The script successfully updates the folder's owner

---

**Research**

Per this question: [Insufficient permissions for this file, unable to share link, 403](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35095459/11163122)

And this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-google/issues/58

I think I need to add the proper scope (`../auth/drive`) to my OAuth consent screen.

---

**Question**

When I try to add the `../auth/drive` scope, Google says `Sensitive scope that requires verification`.  I don't have a `homepage URL` nor a `privacy policy URL`.

- How can I add this scope without requiring verification and/or an authorized domain?
- Or am I doing something totally different wrong?

Comment: Can I confirm your situation? About `I try to transfer ownership of a folder containing one jpg file`, where are the folder and the jpg file? Are those in your Google Drive? And who is the owner of the folder and the jpg file?

Comment: @Tanaike yes I am the owner of both the folder + file inside.  The folder is located inside my Google Drive.  I also updated the question with this information

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, you want to transfer the owner of the folder and the files in the folder from you to other user who is the Google account. I could understand like this. If my understanding is correct, can you provide the script for replicating your issue? Because from your question, I cannot understand about it.

Comment: Okay yes @Tanaike I have updated my question again with more information.  I use the `transfer.py` script in the GitHub repo (linked in question).  I also added how I call `transfer.py`.  Does that help?  Do you need more information?

Comment: Do you think the problem is that I have a regular google account email, not a member of G Suite?

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see on [Google's support page](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en), Google Drive's API is currently a sensitive scope and will soon launch as a restricted scope in March. There are very strict requirements and application processes that you have to sign up for if you want to authorize your OAuth application for that scope. If you only want to authorize yourself for the scope, you can get an authorization code from the [Google OAuth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). Just find the Drive API, authorize yourself, and get your authorization code.

Comment: to confirm, what I really wanted to do was recursively transfer ownership of files/folders from my own personal google drive to a friend's drive.  Can I do so via the playground?

Comment: You should be able to get the authorization code from the playground then enter it in to your program.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet

Step 1: Turn on the Drive API
Click this button to create a new Cloud Platform project and automatically enable the Drive API:

Enable the Drive API

In resulting dialog click DOWNLOAD CLIENT CONFIGURATION and save the file credentials.json to your working directory.